# Can somebody explain about DashO concept in obfuscating?

Tags: android, obfuscation

can somebody please help me to know about DashO concept in obfuscating android app with proguard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Your question isn't terribly clear. Proguard is one obfuscation product, DashO is another.

DashO is a commercial product, so you'd need to license it, and they don't provide pricing info. They prefer to talk to you and provide a quote (which always looks a bit like seeing what you can afford and charging you that, but there ya go). It does however have other features beyond obfuscation, such as adding exception tracking and reporting code to your program.

Proguard is the open-source obfuscation tool that is already built into the android build process. It's very popular, quite effective, and free :) I think you'll find that due to [official support](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) it is the obfuscation tool used by most people on android, and quite simple to use.

OK, well responding to your comment below:

According to Proguard at least, Proguard does preverification, and DashO does not. This may be out of date - I suggest you check with the DashO people. Source: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#alternatives.html

In case you're wondering what preverification is, see point no. 3 here: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#FAQ.html (I would link directly to that point but their re-framing code breaks the anchor).

It's also worth noting that while Proguard is just an obfuscator and optimizer, DashO also has other features such as watermarking (embedding copyright info in the jar), error reporting, and "calling home" in other ways to report tampering, monitoring and usage tracking info, etc. Whether you want to pay for it depends on how useful you find these features. The error reporting in particular could be achieved with something like ACRA (http://code.google.com/p/acra/), and there are many analytics packages out there, including Google's own.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just need to know more about DashO can u prefer me any links that you know, that will be more helpful for me.